# Bring an activity in front of the phone call activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, phone-call

I am working on an *Android Application* where I have to intercept a phone call and after launch an Activity that will be visible in front of the *phone call Activity*!

Is it possible ? Or can we modify the real *phone call activity* ?

Here is the code of the listener :

```
private Context context;

public CallStateListener(Context cnxt) {
    this.context = cnxt;

}

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(context, UserInteraction.class) ;
        context.startActivity(callIntent) ; 


        break;


    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

With this code, when the phone call is detected, The *userInteraction activity* will appear behind the *phone call Activity*!

Is there a way that to show the *UserInteraction activity* in the first plane, in front of the *phone call activity* ?

It means make the *UserInteraction activity*, the activity showed when a user receives a phone call instead of the default one ?

Comment: the _phone call activity_ is the activity shown when a phone call is received !

Comment: While I'm not certain, I think it might not be possible to come in front of the phone call activity. The phone app is specially blessed, and has specific treatment no other activity has. Also, being able to do that would allow apps to do dangerous things like spying on calls, etc...

Comment: Okay.Suppose that we can not bring to front activities in front of the phone call activity but can we modify the phone call activity itself ?